# default session file Permits

Tags: php.ini

i need to edit the default permits of the session file

i know it's high security risk,

The default permits is :600

```
[root@server sessions]# stat sess_06pqdthgi49oq7jnlvuvsr95q1
  File: `sess_06pqdthgi49oq7jnlvuvsr95q1'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 32473090    Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 5003/     ...)   Gid: ( 5003/     ...)
```

i want set default permits to `0777`

This is my `php.in`

```
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
;session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
session.save_path = "/sessions"
```

i've changed the `session.save_path` to

```
session.save_path = "N;644;/sessions"
```

The new results is:

```
  File: `sess_avrc5442qjkcbd17g2qkenmit2'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 32473090    Links: 1
Access: (0700/-rwx------)  Uid: ( 5003/     ...)   Gid: ( 5003/     ...)
```

it's now `0700` NOT `0777`

WHY?

Answer (score 1):

Try `umask(0)` before `session_start()`. There are better ways of doing this with `setacl` on the folder.